# Get all the combinations of a given set of elements with permutation in r

Tags: r, dataframe, permutation

I have two parameters (say "A" and "B"), that need to be tested against a set of treatments ("PD", "MO", "K") applied alone or in combination, in addition to not having any treatment ("."). I need to get all the possible combinations of treatments affecting parameters "A" and "B". I came with a very rudimentary way to do it, but I need a more efficient way to do it because a have a large list of treatments.

This is my reproducible example

```
effects <- c(".", "PD", "MO", "PD,MO", "K", "K,PD", "K,MO", "K,PD,MO")

res.perm <- permutations(n = 8, r = 2, v = effects, repeats.allowed = TRUE)
print(res.perm, quote = FALSE)
```

An this is what I get

[image]

.....

[image]

If someone could provide a more elegant or smart way to do it, it would be great. The input I actually need to use is `V1 = c("PD", "MO", "K")`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `expand.grid(effects, effects)`

Comment: @DarrenTsai, yes, that could be an option. But I would need a way to avoid the need to write down all the interactions in the "effects" vector.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Do you need `crossing(effects, effects1 = effects)`

Comment: @GregorThomas, Yes, that's true. The input should be ```c("PD", "MO", "K")```. Exactly. The "permutations" code is working. The output I need is the one I obtained. But the issue is actually with the input.

Comment: @GregorThomas, That's true. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could get the `combn`ations of the `vector` ('v1') for 1 to 3 'm' in a loop (`lapply`), `paste` them to a single string (`toString`), `unlist`, `replicate` the it twice into a `list` and apply `expand.grid` on it

```
expand.grid(replicate(2, unlist(c(".", lapply(1:3, 
  function(i) combn(v1, i, FUN = toString)))), simplify = FALSE))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("PD", "MO", "K")
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution